# Percentages per year per value

Tags: r, count, percentage

My data

```
Chemical  date      concentration  limit
A     01-01-2016     0.2         0.01
A     01-02-2016     0.2         0.01
A     01-01-2017     0.005       0.01
A     01-02-2017     0.2         0.01
B     01-01-2016     0.3         0.1
B     01-02-2016     0.05        0.1
B     01-01-2017     0.2         0.1
B     01-02-2017     0.2         0.1
C     01-01-2016     1.2         1
C     01-02-2016     0.8         1
C     01-01-2017     0.9         1
C     01-02-2017     0.9         1
```

I want to show the percentage of every chemical when it exceeds the limit per year (notice that every limit is different). So I would like to get something like this

```
Year   A         B     C
2016   100%     50%   50%
2017   50%      100%   0
```

I already have the code to count the times each chemical exceeds per year, but when doing for the percentages I get it wrong.

This I have to count the times.

```
  library(tidyverse)
   counts<- data %>% 
   group_by(Chemical, grp = format(date, format = '%Y')) %>% 
   mutate(exceed = concentration >= limit) %>% # TRUE/FALSE
   summarise(tot_exceed = sum(exceed)) %>%  # count each T/F
   spread(Chemical, tot_exceed, fill = 0)
```

so I get this

```
   Year   A     B    C
   2016   2     1    1
   2017   1     2    0
```

and for the percentages, I tried this.

```
percentage_exceed<- data %>% 
group_by(Chemical, grp = format(date, format = '%Y')) %>% 
mutate(exceed = concentration >= limit, countconc = length(concentration)) 
%>% 
summarise(percent = (sum(exceed)/countconc)*100) %>% 
spread(Chemical, percent, fill = 0)
```

But I don't get the result I want. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt = read.table(text = "
Chemical  date      concentration  limit
A     01-01-2016     0.2         0.01
A     01-02-2016     0.2         0.01
A     01-01-2017     0.005       0.01
A     01-02-2017     0.2         0.01
B     01-01-2016     0.3         0.1
B     01-02-2016     0.05        0.1
B     01-01-2017     0.2         0.1
B     01-02-2017     0.2         0.1
C     01-01-2016     1.2         1
C     01-02-2016     0.8         1
C     01-01-2017     0.9         1
C     01-02-2017     0.9         1
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dt %>%
  mutate(year = year(dmy(date))) %>%
  group_by(year, Chemical) %>%
  summarise(Total = n(),
            Num_exceed = sum(concentration >= limit)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Prc = paste0(Num_exceed / Total * 100,"%")) %>%
  select(year, Chemical, Prc) %>%
  spread(Chemical, Prc)

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#    year A     B     C    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1  2016 100%  50%   50%  
# 2  2017 50%   100%  0%
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

 data  %>% 
   mutate(yr=mdy(date) %>% year) %>% 
   group_by(Chemical,yr) %>% 
   mutate(exceed  = ifelse(concentration>=limit,1,0  )) %>% 
   summarise(tot_exceed =sum(exceed)) %>% 
   group_by(Chemical) %>% 
   mutate(proc=tot_exceed/max(tot_exceed)*100) %>% 
   select(-tot_exceed) %>% 
   spread(Chemical,proc)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     yr     A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2016   100    50   100
2  2017    50   100     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly fine, you just need to replace `sum` by `mean` and to multiply by a 100:

```
data %>% group_by(Chemical, grp = format(date, format = '%Y')) %>% 
  mutate(exceed = concentration >= limit) %>% 
  summarise(tot_exceed = mean(exceed) * 100) %>%
  spread(Chemical, tot_exceed, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   grp       A     B     C
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2016    100    50    50
# 2 2017     50   100     0
```

The line in your attempt

```
summarise(percent = (sum(exceed)/countconc) * 100)
```

does almost that: the error is about the fact that `countconc` is the whole column rather than a single value (which is needed for summarizing). So, since it is a *constant* column in every group anyway, you could have written, e.g.,

```
summarise(percent = (sum(exceed)/countconc[1]) * 100)
```

But given the line before,

```
mutate(exceed = concentration >= limit, countconc = length(concentration))
```

it is ultimately just a mean, so we are back to the code at the beginning of my answer.

Also note that using `lubridate` you could write the first line as

```
data %>% group_by(Chemical, Year = year(date)) %>%
```

---

Something very concise but perhaps not in the format that you want

```
data %>% group_by(Chemical, Year = year(date)) %>% 
  summarise(Percentage = mean(concentration > limit) * 100)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Chemical [?]
#   Chemical  Year Percentage
#   <fct>    <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 A         2016        100
# 2 A         2017         50
# 3 B         2016         50
# 4 B         2017        100
# 5 C         2016         50
# 6 C         2017          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` and `reshape2` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(date = str_sub(as.character(date), 7, 10)) %>% #Taking out the year from "date"
 group_by(date, Chemical) %>% #Group by "date" and "Chemical"
 summarise(temp = length(concentration[concentration > limit])/n()*100) %>% #Applying the condition
 dcast(date~Chemical, value.var = "temp") #Reshaping the data

  date   A   B  C
1 2016 100  50 50
2 2017  50 100  0
```

Or with just `tidyverse` using `spread()`

```
df %>%
 mutate(date = str_sub(as.character(date), 7, 10)) %>% #Taking out the year from "date"
 group_by(date, Chemical) %>% #Group by "date" and "Chemical"
 summarise(temp = length(concentration[concentration > limit])/n()*100) %>% #Applying the condition
 spread(Chemical, temp, fill = 0) #Reshaping the data
```